# Problem with installing Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on my second HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb, hard-drive

I have a computer that was using Windows 7. Now, I bought another HDD so that I can dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I unplugged the old hard drive and plugged the new one. Then, I booted Ubuntu with my USB key and I installed it. After I clicked on *Restart*, I got my USB key out and the computer just went into the BIOS menu. I asked my brother to help, but he didn’t figure out what was the problem. After doing *Erase disk and install Ubuntu* several times, he noticed that if we click on the *x* on the top-right corner of the install window, we can just try the OS desktop. Then, I went on this website to look for help. Here are some of my specs:
CPU: Intel i3-4330
GPU: MSi Radeon RX 560
RAM: 16GB DDR3

Does anybody know what is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enter
sudo update-grub?
The update-grub often solves the problems related to booting.  Of course, you need to check BIOS to see that that the boot key is disabled. The boot key prevemts booting of "unknown" operating systems, including ubuntu. In fact, any linux os... 
OldAl

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I successfully installed Ubuntu 18.04 by installing the 16.04 version first, then upgrading it to the 18.04 version. Thanks anyway.